# Get/list prefixes from XPath expression

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have some `XML` ([`XBRL`](https://www.xbrl.org/) actually) documents containing some elements whose `test` attribute contain an XPath expression:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<link:linkbase 
    xmlns:ea="http://xbrl.org/2008/assertion/existence"
    xmlns:generic="http://xbrl.org/2008/generic" 
    xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xff="http://www.xbrl.org/2010/function/formula">

  <generic:link xlink:role="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/link" xlink:type="extended">

  <!-- .... -->
  <va:valueAssertion 
    ... some attribs ...
    test="if(xff:has-fallback-value(xs:QName('someQName'))) then false() else (count($someVariable) ge 1)"
    />

  <!-- ... -->
  </generic:link>
</link:linkbase>
```

The convention for processing the XPath expression is, that it uses the same namespaces for prefixes as declared in the XML document.

We also have some (custom) linting mechanism with a rule that checks if declared prefixes and their namespace are "used" within the document.

This means that in the xml example above, the xff and xs prefixes should be recognised as "used", since they are present in the XPath expression. Standard tooling (within Java) however, doesn't help us see that this is the case.

I could, for example, take al the prefixes in scope and check if I can find "prefix:" within the XPath string; but this seems like a very buggy solution and prone for both false positives and false negatives.

An other way would be to "just" evaluate the XPath expression using all the possible combination of namespace bindings and check what the minimal set of namespaces is. This won't over everything either, since the evaluation could skip an entire branch of code. (When an if statement is encountered, for example). Secondly, the explosion of possibilities increases quite quickly since we're talking about many (~100s) of documents containing multiple XPath expressions.

Does anyone know of a[n] (good) approach to tackle this issue? Currently, we're using Scala on the JVM to implement the checks. So either a native Java or Scala solution is preferred. Other JVM languages or depending on non-java tooling is acceptable if need-be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `javax.xml.xpath.XPath#compile(String)` to parse all XPath expressions in a document.

To know what namespaces prefixes are referenced in the expression prepare a `NamespaceContext` implementation which records the prefixes of the requested namespace bindings and set it via `XPath#setNamespaceContext(NamespaceContext)` before you call the compile method.

Based on that prefix list and given the namespace bindings on the attribute which holds the expression string you can then build a list of all used namespaces.

Comment: Intriguing approach! Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this mean _evaluating_ the expression as well? (i.e. not _solely_ compiling it?) I didn't explicitly state that in my question, but the nature of the problem is as such that we would need to generate multiple input documents in order to evaluate all XPath expressions. The nature of XBRL assertions is such that some filtering takes place first; if nothing is left over, the expression will not be used. Since we're looking for (static) analysis of code; we would like to be as agnostic about the context of the expression.

Comment: @mhogerheijde compiling does *not* mean evaluating. It gives you the exact list of namespace prefixes used by the expression. But your comment seem to indicate that your problem can not be solved by static analysis alone. Then in your case I would reconsider to broaden the linting requirements

Comment: We can get away with static analysis I think. For example, when someone would use String concatenation to create a prefix, that would probably issue a false negative; but that should be solved by the creator of the XML document. My confusion about compiling and evaluation arose due to the fact that I thought that the NamespaceContext would only be used during evaluation, but apparently I was wrong about that. I'm giving your solution a try, thanks!